# How to delete datetime value using update?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

I have a row with datetime. What I want to achieve is delete the datetime in just a blank. Is that possible with using update? If possible I don't want to delete and re-insert the data because this is what I tried and it so inefficient.

Here is my table:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ ID  + Name +        AppvlDt       +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  1  +  JB  +  02/11/2019 00:00:00 +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I want to delete the AppvlDt into just a plain blank. Is that possible using Update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly null out your datetime field, e.g.

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET AppvlDt = NULL
WHERE ID = 1;
```

Whether or not doing this actually makes sense depends on other things though.

Comment: My system processes the application when there is a date inside the field

Comment: @Blank317, null is different to plain blank.

Comment: @Metal Actually in Oracle empty string and null are the same thing.

Comment: NULL is better I am getting an error when I use  = ''

Answer (score 0):

Just run this `DML` script.

```
update table Set AppvlDt = ''
```